# SubSonic 3 and Linq Parameterized Queries

Tags: linq, subsonic3, parameterized

We are currently using SubSonic 3.0.0.2 and playing about with the Linq for it, we've noticed that the underlying SQL is not parameterized.

I'm aware that the query tool is and we can work with that but I'm just curious if having parameterized with Linq is possible?

Am I missing something? or is this not yet implemented in SubSonic.

Cheers
Tony

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is parameterized - just not for constant values (stuff you embed in code). If you use a variable then it will be.

Comment: in Parameterizer.cs you have the following code:
protected override Expression VisitConstant(ConstantExpression c)
        {
            if (c.Value != null && !IsNumeric(c.Value.GetType())) {
                ....

Is there a reason you do not parameterize numeric values?